# Moving a vertex of a Bézier Curve moves the origin point of a mesh with array+curve modifier (why and how to stop)

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, vertices, origin

[image]
(Original video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zu0r.jpg)

So, I set up a Bézier curve and made a rope mesh follow it with the curve and array modifiers. Then I hooked up each Vertex of the curve to an empty (Goal is to animate tying knots as tutorials). Everything works like a charm. When I move/rotate the empties, my rope will move and rotate as well. Great!
Only, when moving this one single vertex (the one that has by default(?) red coloured handles), the entire mesh is offset from the curve (or collapsed inwards when I move the vertex along the x axis). Further testing yielded that apparently when moving that vertex of the curve, the origin point of the mesh is moved as well. Has anyone an idea what is causing this/ how to fix this? It happens only with this single vertex, and for the animation especially of the more complicated knots I need to have every single vertex be able to move freely without messing up everything else.

Thank you so much in advance and have a great day!

Comment: I would guess your mesh is parented to that first empty

Comment: As @HenrikD i can also only **guess**, thus i would suggest that you could/should provide a redacted version of the **.blend** file, as it would allow checking settings and such that can't be seen in the video. You can use the [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) service for that.

Comment: @HenrikD Thanks, that was the right call, I feel so stupid now... Thank you again!

Comment: And @Xylvier, I will keep the suggestion in mind should I ever have a problem again, but sometimes just getting the right impulse in form of a guess is enough apparently to solve a problem :-)
Thanks again, everyone and have a great evening/day :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so @HenrikD was right indeed; for some reason there was an empty that the whole mesh was parented to. CLearing the parent and setting up the curve modifier anew was enough to solve the problem.